# Using population as weights in regional-level data

Tags: multiple-regression, stata, population, weighted-regression

I'm analyzing regional-level data (variously at the level of metro, micro, and county levels depending on their economic integration/population agglomeration). I'm using STATA 12 SE. It seems intuitive to use the populations as weights so as to not count very small areas as having the same impact as NYC / SF / LA etc.

As far as I know I have these options:

1. Use WLS0 for weighted least squares results
2. Run regular regression using `aweights=population` and robust standard errors

Can anybody illuminate the differences between these approaches, and possibly recommend a strategy going forward? I'm more used to using `svyset` type commands, which don't make sense here.

Comment: Exemplify how your data look like, and what kind of regression you want to run. If you have something like output per capita and capital per capita, and you want to estimate the region production function, then I would probably just create the new variables that are products of your existing per capita variables and population, and run regression among them; and then check whether `regress [aw]` gives identical point estimates and standard errors.